# How to import PST extracted from Exchange db to linux IMAP server?

Tags: imap, import, outlook

I had an Exchange 2000 server that crashed, I recovered the PST mailboxes from the .edb database.

Now I'll move to a linux webhosting with imap support. I've to import the PST contents in the respective new mailboxes on the new server.

I've already tried several ways:

1- OUTLOOK IMPORT: Importing using import/export wizard fails because it complains about destination folder containing different "type of objects" (Note: translation from italian message) than the source one

2- OUTLOOK MOVING FOLDERS: tried to attach PST to outlook and move folders of mailbox in the IMAP mailbox also connected to outlook... but same way: impossible to move folders: I have to create every single folder and move the mails into (but is a big PITA for 16 Gb of mailboxes)

3- Using Linux converted PST to MBOX using "readpst" on ubuntu, then tried to import using ImportExportTools from Thunderbird extensions, but again no luck, I can just put this in local storage but not import these folders directly in IMAP account.

anybody can help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

[readpst](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/rn01re01.html) can convert PST files to mbox format

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to successfully convert your `PST` files into `MBOX` format, then there are a variety of tools you can use to import those messages into an IMAP server, including:

- [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)
- [imap-upload](http://imap-upload.sourceforge.net/)

Both may already be packaged for your distribution.

Comment: Tried this but readpst splits every PST mail subfolder in a different mbox file, so I'll have to restore manually (or script something) the folder structure on the imap server.. a bit too long. thanks by the way. I'll use imapsync to sync the mails from the temporary server to the definitive one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Mailstore](http://www.mailstore.com/). It's possible to archive and export mailboxes of variant sources. The 30 Day trial is a full version. I'd use it for moving E-Mails from a Linux Mail Server to Microsoft Exchange.

> Archiving of Emails From Different Sources
>
> - Microsoft Exchange Server 2003, 2007, and 2010 (incl. SBS)
> - Hosted Exchange
> - Microsoft Office 365
> - MDaemon Messaging Server
> - IceWarp Mail Server
> - Kerio Connect
> - Any IMAP- or POP3-compatible email server or mailbox
> - Email clients such as Microsoft Outlook and Mozilla Thunderbird
> - PST and other email file formats

Comment: This software is the best-fitting solution to my problem. thanks a lot.Anyway I had to use readpst to convert quickly all the Contacts in vCard format to import in Thunderbird clients.

Comment: I have to say there's a problem with this software in doing it right... many subjects and dates are invalid once imported into IMAP folders... I'm trying other ways

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some recent tools that can be used for same:

- https://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/rn01re01.html
- https://github.com/rgladwell/imap-upload

So, pipeline will look something like that:

*.pst -> readpst -> *.box -> imap_upload.py -> IMAP server